# Prevent file from deleted in usb drive yet keep the drive remaining space writable

Tags: hard-drive, usb, permissions

My situation is we will give out usb drive to people to use, which bundled a software for promotional purpose. We don't want this software be deleted by user, yet still let users use the usb drive as they want.

I've used the Windows write permission mechanism, but no matter which combination of permission options I use, I plug the usb to another computer and I can still delete the file. Is it something impossible to achieve, or am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: You could use diskpart and set one of the partitions to be read-only https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766465(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Thank you richie, I've also look into this solution, but as I know Windows can only sees the first partition but not the others. And as most people use Windows so this seems not feasible for me.

Comment: Yes;  This is impossible.  Anything you do to the drive can be reversed by an Administrator on their own machine.  The only exception might be at the manufacture level itself, (i.e. the firmware itself prevents the read-only partition from being deleted) but even then the firmware in theory could be modified to allow it.

Comment: Hi Ramhound, I understand that. Actually I accept any solution that can prevent a non-technical person to delete the file. That means I won't try to prevent someone from updating file permissions by himself or even format the usb drive. But it seems to me even avoid deleting file from layman is hard to achieve already.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot prevent a user from deleting data from writeable media.